# Unable to run Cryptogen

Tags: linux, binary, hyperledger-fabric, sample

I try to run Cryptogen but an error appears, when I'm executing the command.

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap- 
1.0.1.sh | bash
bash: line 1: 404:: command not found
```

Comment: First of all, you are not trying to run Cryptogen as it looks like. If you are trying to install it just follow the tutorial below.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/install.html

Comment: Also adjust title and description, after you know, what exactly you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

You have a long way to go. And your question is incomplete. You need to tell us he operating system you are using. Also, the version of the Hyperledger Fabric documentation that you found this at.

The command that you ran only downloads the code, binaries, and docker images. It looks like you are trying to run this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh

which is then piped into bash. But it is failing to find that URL.